# Residually solvable Bianchi groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $d$ be a square-free positive integer, and let $\mathcal{O}_d$ be the ring of integers of the quadratic imaginary number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$. Consider the Bianchi group $\Gamma_d = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal{O}_d)$. Is $\Gamma_d$ known to be residually solvable? I am also interested in the case of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathcal{O}_d)$.

As mentioned in the comments, $\Gamma_d$ is never residually nilpotent.

(I might be overlooking something easy, sorry!)

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ (and its overgroups) has elements of order 4 and 3 that don't commute, so it's not residually nilpotent.

Comment: For $d=3$, an index 12 subgroup is the figure 8 knot group which is residually solvable since it is free-by-cyclic. So this group is residually solvable.

Comment: @IanAgol is this index 12 subgroup a normal subgroup? otherwise it is unclear how to conclude.

Comment: In some papers (e.g. by Grunewald) the Bianchi group rather means the quotient PSL2 by $\pm 1$. Some little argument might be needed to show that residual solvability holds for SL2 iff it holds for PSL2.

Comment: @YCor No, the figure eight knot subgroup mentioned by IanAgol is quite far from normal.

Comment: @YCor I noticed this, much like “the modular group” can refer to either $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. I’d be happy with an answer for either.

Comment: I was wondering whether for $d=5$ this group contains the binary icosahedral group (perfect of order 120 — or 60 if you work in PSL2).

Comment: @YCor I think $PSL_2(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}))$ shouldn't contain $A_5$. To have any element of order 5 would require that the 2-by-2 matrix algebra over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ as subfield. But subfields contained in the matrix algebra have to have degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, and the quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt thanks! this works for $\mathrm{(P)SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ for every squarefree $d$ as well. So there is no obstruction coming from finite subgroups.

Comment: @YCor you’re right, I didn’t think this through carefully.

Comment: Eventually it seems likely to hold for all $d$.

Answer (score 8):

This is true for $d=3$. Let $\zeta=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, $\mathcal{O_3}=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. The principal congruence subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathcal{O}_3)$ of level $1+\zeta$, which divides $3$, is a normal subgroup whose quotient is solvable (see picture of sequence of orbifold covers or prove algebraically).

[image]

Principal congruence subgroups are residually $p$, and hence residually nilpotent.

I think Chapter 1 of the [thesis of Matthias Goerner](https://www.unhyperbolic.org/research.html) should yield more examples.

This should also be true for $d=1$. There is a solvable cover corresponding to the 1-skeleton of an octahedron with edges labeled 2, which is index 2 in a right-angled Coxeter group. A right-angled Coxeter group is residually 2, hence residually nilpotent.

Answer (score 6):

(Inspired by [Ian Agol's answer for d=3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461313/14094))

It seems to be true if $d$ is not $19$ modulo $24$. Indeed in this case $\mathcal{O}_d$ surjects as a ring onto either $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ or $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ (see below). Since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ is solvable for $p=2,3$ and the principal congruence subgroup is residually nilpotent, we're done.

If $d$ is not $3$ modulo $4$, then $\mathcal{O}_d$ is reduced to $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$, hence surjects as a ring onto $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Suppose henceforth that $d$ is $3$ modulo $4$.
Then $\mathcal{O}_d$ is generated by $(1+\sqrt{-d})/2$ which has the minimal polynomial $X^2-X+(1+d)/4$.

If $d$ is $7$ modulo $8$, this minimal polynomial is $X^2+X$ modulo 2, so $\mathcal{O}_d$ surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

If $d$ is not $1$ modulo $3$ then modulo $3$ the above polynomial is $X^2-X$ or $X^2-X+1$ which has a root modulo $3$, so $\mathcal{O}_d$ surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$.

If $d$ is $19$ modulo $24$ (i.e., $3$ modulo $8$ and $1$ modulo $3$), the above minimal polynomial is $X^2+X+1$ modulo $2$ and $X^2-X-1$ modulo $3$, both irreducible, so $\mathcal{O}_d$ surjects onto neither $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ nor $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$, and $\mathrm{SL}_2$ of larger finite fields are not solvable, so the argument cannot work. But this doesn't imply any conclusion. What about $d=19$?

Comment: An explicit presentation of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathcal{O}_7)$ is given by Grunewald-Schwermer p6 (p52 in journal) [link at AMS website](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-335-01/S0002-9947-1993-1020042-6/S0002-9947-1993-1020042-6.pdf). In particular, the abelianization is $\simeq \mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: It seems like $O_7$ surjects $Z/2$ since 2 splits. So I’m not sure your case analysis is complete.

Comment: @IanAgol thanks a lot: indeed this covers when $d$ is $7$ modulo $24$, which I indeed missed. I corrected the post: precisely $\mathcal{O}_d$ has no quotient field of cardinal $\le 3$ iff $d$ is $19$ mod $24$.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks! Just one question: why is the principal congruence subgroup residually $p$?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Let $G$ be $\mathrm{GL}_d(R)$ for $R$ a noetherian domain, and $M$ a maximal ideal in $R$. Let $G_n$ be the kernel of $\mathrm{GL}_d(R)\to\mathrm{GL}_d(R/M^nR)$. So $\mathrm{GL}_d(R)=G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\dots$. Krull's intersection theorem ensures that $\bigcap_n M^n=0$, so $\bigcap_n G_n=1$. Then $G_n/G_{n+1}$ is naturally a finite-dim vector space over $R/M$. Hence if $R/M$ a finite field of characteristic $p$, then $G_n/G_{n+1}$ is a finite elementary abelian $p$-group, so $G_1/G_n$ is a finite $p$-group for all $n\ge 1$, and $G_1$ is residually-$p$.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for spelling that out! (Implicit: every principal congruence subgroup is contained in one of level $q$ where $q$ is prime, and being residually $p$ is inherited by subgroups).

Answer (score 4):

I am posting this answer (slightly edited) on behalf of Alan Reid:

$PSL(2,\mathcal{O}_{19})$ is not residually solvable. In fact it
doesn't have any non-abelian solvable quotients.

Here is the proof.

Let $G=PSL(2,\mathcal{O}_{19})$ which can be presented as

$<a,b,t,u | a^2, (ta)^3, b^3, (bt^{-1})^3, (ab)^2, (at^{-1}ubu^{-1})^2, [t,u]>$.

See p. 75 of

*Swan, Richard G.*, [**Generators and relations for certain special linear groups**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(71)90027-2), Adv. Math. 6, 1-77 (1971). [ZBL0221.20060](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0221.20060)

which gives a presentation of $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_{19})$ (kill the center $J$ to get the above presentation of $PSL_2(\mathcal{O}_{19})$).

[image: extract from Swan’s paper]

It is easy to check that the abelianization of $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ (generated by
the image of $u$).

In fact setting $a=1$ (resp. $b=1$) gives the quotient map onto $\mathbb{Z}$.
Hence $K=[G,G]$ is generated by $G$-conjugates of $a$
(order 2) and $G$-conjugates $b$ (order 3), i.e. $K=\langle\langle a\rangle\rangle=\langle\langle b \rangle\rangle$, and so it follows that $K^{\rm ab}$ must be trivial, i.e. $K$ is perfect.

Thus if $S$ is solvable and $f:G\to S$ is an epimorphism then $f_{|K}$ has
solvable image hence trivial (since its perfect). Hence $S$ is cyclic.

**Addendum:** Alan found an orbifold description in a paper of Mark Baker [Link Complements and the Bianchi Modular Groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/221886)

[image]

One sees that killing the order 2 or order 3 orbifold locus in the middle edges of the figure gives a bad orbifold whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$, giving a geometric proof of the above algebraic argument.

Comment: That's beautifully simple - thank you (and say hi to Alan from me)!

Comment: Nice. The next cases are thus $d=43$, $67$, $91$... are there available presentations then?

Comment: @YCor it looks like Hatcher has worked these out for PGL  from data of Riley (or one couple probably work directly with Riley’s data to get a presentation). https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Bianchi.pdf

Comment: I checked that a similar perfect subgroup exists (the normal closure of elements of order 2 and 3) when d=43.